# sqrt(x)sin(x)=1/2

Tags: trigonometry

Hello mathematically capable people. I was asked for a help with this equation and it kinda turns out I too don't know how to solve it.
$$
\sqrt x\cdot \sin x=\frac12
$$
I'm more interested in the steps (or the generic approach) rather than the result (since I already plotted the function).

Thanks for any advice how to approach this.

Comment: I don't think there are any steps to solve this exactly.

Comment: there are infinity many solutions,take a numerical method,eg the Newton-Raphson method